# OCEJWCD questions

Tags: jsp, security, servlets, web-deployment

I'm preparing for OCEJWCD and there're some questions where Whizlabs and Enthuware answers don't match with what I find out when I run my code and test them out. Your help in resolving these is deeply appreciated.

**Question 1:**
**The authority of servlet security implementations over each other when used on the same URL pattern**

This is about the scenario where security constraints have been defined on the same URL pattern using all the three implementations,

1. The security-constraint element in web.xml
2. The setServletSecurity method of ServletRegistration.Dynamic interface
3. The @Servletsecurity annotation in the servlet

The answers in the mock exams state that the order of authority (which one overpowers the others when the URL pattern matches for all 3)
is 1 (most powerful), 2 and then 3

But when I run the code I see that that @ServletSecurity annotation is more powerful then setServletSecurity method of ServletRegistration.Dynamic interface. **Which one is correct??**

**Question 2:**
**jsp:useBean error if used on a class NOT having a no-arg constructor**

There's a common question in the exams that ask what would happen if jsp:useBean is used on a class to instantiate it but the class does NOT have a no-arg constructor.

Let's take an example, I have a class employee

```
public class Employee {

    private Integer employeeId;

    private String name;

    public Employee(Integer employeeId, String name) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(Integer employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And no object already exists in any of the four scopes and I have this in the jsp

```
<jsp:useBean id="employee" class="com.kingshuk.model.Employee" />
```

I believe it'll throw a runtime exception because tomcat tries to do something like this

```
com.kingshuk.model.Employee employee = null;
boolean _jspx_specialmb  = false;
synchronized (pageContext) {
    employee= (com.kingshuk.model.Employee)pageContext.getAttribute("employee",PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE);
    if ( employee == null ) {
        _jspx_specialmb = true;
        try {
            employee = (com.kingshuk.model.Employee)     java.beans.Beans.instantiate(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), "com.kingshuk.model.Employee");
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            throw new ServletException (" Cannot create bean of class "+"com.kingshuk.model.Employee", exc);
        }
        pageContext.setAttribute("employee", employee, PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE);
    }
}
```

But some of the answers say it'll throw a compilation error not throw an exception at runtime. **Which one is correct??**

Any help I can get is deeply appreciated before my exam on July 26th.

Thanks,
Kingshuk

Comment: You have asked two completely unrelated questions, so they should appear in two separate posts with the appropriate tags. Also, why not raise these issues directly with Whizlabs and Enthuware? I don't know about Whizlabs, but Enthuware are very responsive to questions from their users.

Comment: I have raised these to Whizlabs and their answers didn't satisfy me. And I didn't know about the requirement of posting different topics in different posts. Will remember that going forward.

Comment: OK, and what about Enthuware - did their answer also not satisfy you? Also, it would be helpful to specify the relevant versions for JSP, Servlets and EE for your questions. For example, are you referring to EE 6?